# concat two columns in pyspark & add a text in between

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I'm using pyspark in 3.0.1 in Databricks. My pyspark dataframe ,df, contains a column Year with value like 2012 & another Column Quarter with number 1,2,3 & 4. I want to join Year & quarter & create another column `year_qtr` & it should contain value like `2012 Quarter-1`
I tried following code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
col_list = ['Year'," Quarter-",'Quarter']
df.withColumn("year_qtr", f.format_string('Year',' Quarter-','Quarter')).show()
```

But I'm getting error message

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '` Quarter-`'
```

Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a format string in the first argument, just like how you would do it in Python. The subsequent arguments would correspond to the arguments inside the format string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn("year_qtr", F.format_string('%d Quarter-%d', 'Year', 'Quarter'))
```

Use `%s` if the columns are of string type. `%d` is only suitable for int type columns.

---

Alternatively, you can use `concat`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn("year_qtr", F.concat('Year', F.lit(' Quarter-'), 'Quarter'))
```